# Is marrying an orphan girl considered a greater good deed?

Tags: nikah, islamic-philosophy, deeds

Is it mentioned anywhere in the Quran or Hadith that marrying an orphan girl is a great thing?

I have heard that Allah loves those who take care of orphans. I did a lot of searching, but it speaks about taking care of orphan children and the rules associated with it.

I am not looking for an opinion, but an authoritative answer on this matter.

Comment: check this question http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12753/8155

Answer (score 1):

In ignorance arab times they used to bring orphan girls to their house take care of them and they married them and betrayed them to acquire all of their properties and then they would left these poor girls anytime even with no Mahr. God in Al-Nisa (4:3) http://quran.com/4 is telling them to marry orphans but take care of being righteous to them. Even you could marry four women in case of being righteous with them and if you worry about being righteous just marry one.

Be careful God talked very strongly about the rights of orphans.
I wish I had your situation. Sure your life will be full of barkah if you be righteous to your orphan wife and in next world you will be proud :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course if you can justly deal with her and give her all rights in Islam then Allah will reward you for that. A lot of Ahadith mention situation such as yours and point towards a bit more reward.